# Why cant I build firefox for android?

Tags: firefox, build, mozilla, gecko

I am trying to build firefox for android (fennec) using the instruction on [this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Simple_Firefox_for_Android_build#Artifact_mode)

However, when I try to get the dependency through the terminal command on the site, it give me the instruction to type either "Firefox for Desktop", "Firefox for Android", "Firefox for Desktop Artifact Mode", or "Firefox for Android Artifact Mode". but when I press enter after typing "Firefox for Android Artifact Mode", nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and I have python 2.7.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompt for `./mach bootstrap` shows:

> Please choose the version of Firefox you want to build:
>
> 1. Firefox for Desktop Artifact Mode
> 2. Firefox for Desktop
> 3. Firefox for Android Artifact Mode
> 4. Firefox for Android
>
> [... some other text ...]
>
> Your choice:

You should type `3`, not `Firefox for Android Artifact Mode`, to install the requirements.